# “IF” condition to compare two sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to compare two sheets and write results to a third sheet. The first sheet has two columns:

title_add | add something
title_del | del something
title_lst | list something

The second sheet:

add something | add members in group
del something | delete members from group

In the third sheet, the output should be:

{"title_add","add members in group"},
{"title_del","delete members from group"},
{"title_lst","list something"},

[non matching details will be retained]

I have written function that writes to third sheet first column:

{"title_add}

```
IF(sheet1!B1=sheet2!A1, sheet3!A1=CONCATENATE("""",sheet1!A1,""",""",sheet2!B1,"""}"),  
                        sheet3!A1=CONCATENATE("{""",sheet1!A1,""",""",sheet1!B1,"""}"))
```

What's the mistake or rectification required?

Comment: remove the `sheet3!A1=` 's from the formula

Comment: yes, i did that and it worked. i traced the error! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`="{"""&sheet1!A1&""","""&IF(sheet1!B1=sheet2!A1,sheet2!B1,sheet1!B1)&"""},"`